# accessing a file from folder within assets

Tags: android, html, android-assets

I have an application which displays html file from assets folder.
Now the issue is if there is only one html, all works fine but in case I have more than 1 html, how do I refer it?

---

Folder structure when only 1 html is present is like
[image: screen 1]

and I refer to html file as follows:
`InputStream input = this.getAssets().open("index.html");`

---

but in case of multiple html's, it **should/will be** like
 [image: screen 2]

---

So, in this scenario , how do I refer different html's?
**i.e. how do I refer a file from a folder placed within `assets` folder?**

As I have no idea how to proceed, any help appreciated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access it as a URL like so:

`"file:///android_asset/myfile.html"`

So in a WebView you can use the method:

`loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myfile.html")`

Comment: I used `webView1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/HTML 1/index.html");`  and it's working !!!

Answer (score 1):

You can refer like this

> WebView webview;
>
> ```
> webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
>
>         webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
>
>         webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/HTML 1/index.html");   
>
>         webview.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "Android");
> ```

```
final class MyJavaScriptInterface
    {
        public void ProcessJavaScript(final String scriptname, final String args)
            {             
                mHandler.post(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                            {
                             //ToDo Something here...
                            }
                    });
            }
    }
```